# Two QHS monitors & card resolution

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, resolution

I want two QHD monitors, but the required video card resolution is somewhat puzzling. I am looking into the possibility of having one large canvas (5120 pix) or two separate displays of each 2560 pix. Now for the first option I would need certainly a card capable of supporting 5120 horizontal pixels. For the second option - as is the current setup - I am not sure.

Currently, I have a card capable of QHD (9600GT) and two monitors each 1680x1050. Totaling 3360x1050. No problem.
I Have read that a technique like TDMS(?) is responsible for this to happen.

Other responses to similar questions say your card has to be able to support twice the horizontal pixels of the monitors. That is why I am puzzled, since my current configuration does support twice the horizontal pixels, but the card says it limits to 2560 pixels.

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you trying to create a single display resolution (3360x1050) displayed across two displays or two displays running at 3660x1050?  Please edit your question instead of submitting a comment.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the connectors of your graphics card, with 2x DisplayPort I would expect no issues.

btw: At home I am using one 32" with 2560x1440 via DisplayPort, which may be large enough for you as well.
But the curved 34" (3440x1440) at work is even better with multiple windows, moving to another half with just one WinLeft is nicer with a single monitor.

But if you have only two DVI ports, then please check in the monitor and graphics card manuals if [dual link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface) DVI is supported. However I still can not recommend it because of previous trouble with a DP-DVI adapter, where after a driver update only a DP-DP cable without the adapter worked.

What you can always do is to use up to 1920x1200 via HDMI or DVI (two of them are still a little broader than one 34" with 3440x1440).